# Parsing /proc/drbd contents into an array with PHP

Tags: php, arrays, regex, parsing

I'd like to be able to parse the contents of /proc/drbd into an array in order to make use of the data. I'm sure there are some shortcuts or tricks to doing this, but for the life of me, it eludes me!

I assume it's a job for some elaborate regexs?

The text to be parsed is :

```
version: 8.4.3 (api:1/proto:86-101)
srcversion: 6551AD2C98F533733BE558C

 1: cs:Connected ro:Primary/Secondary ds:UpToDate/UpToDate C r-----
    ns:1055689 nr:0 dw:7181 dr:1050351 al:6 bm:64 lo:0 pe:0 ua:0 ap:0 ep:1 wo:f oos:0
 2: cs:Connected ro:Secondary/Primary ds:UpToDate/UpToDate C r-----
    ns:0 nr:1048508 dw:1048508 dr:0 al:0 bm:64 lo:0 pe:0 ua:0 ap:0 ep:1 wo:f oos:0
```

The array might look like :

```
{
   'version' -> '8.4.3',
   'api'     -> '1',
   'proto'   -> '86-101',
   'srcversion' -> '6551AD2C98F533733BE558C',
   'devices' -> array { '1' -> array { 'cs' -> 'Connected', 'ro' -> 'Primary/Secondary', ... , 'oos' -> 0 },
                        '2' -> array { 'cs' -> 'Connected', 'ro' -> 'Secondary/Primary', ... , 'oos' -> 0 } }
}
```

I don't have any examples of stuff I've tried for this as I'm really not even sure where to start. Generally I'd do this with a bunch of explode or preg_match, but I'm fairly sure that's not the right solution, and I'm not sure how to approach data for one entity spread across two lines!

Edit:

There's another variant on the device data format during device rebuilds:

```
 3: cs:SyncTarget ro:Secondary/Primary ds:Inconsistent/UpToDate C r----
    ns:0 nr:284320 dw:284320 dr:0 al:0 bm:17 lo:0 pe:0 ua:0 ap:0 ep:1 wo:b oos:764188
        [====>...............] sync'ed: 27.4% (764188/1048508)K
        finish: 0:15:55 speed: 416 (320) K/sec
```

I'm having trouble working out how to make it ignore these optional second lines.

```
            ((\.+)\R)?
            ((\.+)\R)?
```

On the end of the inner regexp apparently won't work :(

Thanks in advance!

Comment: SO question is what you tried so far?

Comment: As the question says, most of what I've tried so far has been about a year and a half of looking at this problem occasionally and concluding that I've really no idea how best to approach this, and moving on to something else.

The only way I can think of to do it is some very clumsy exploding, which doesn't seem like it's even worth attempting to put into code.

Comment: @adama, have you tried to achieve the expected output without "long" regex ?

Comment: I've partially implemented it using the suggestion below from Jan, but I'm now stuck at handling the extra two lines which occasionally appear depending upon status!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use a combination of regex and programming logic, see [a demo on ideone.com](http://ideone.com/90kNZQ).
The approach uses an outer regex for the `version`, `api`, `proto` and `srcversion` as well as an inner regex for the `devices`. Besides the actual regex (in multiline and verbose mode), the clue is to use the `PREG_SET_ORDER` and named capture groups, so one can loop over the matches afterwards. The inner part consists of splitting the lines and matching pairs of key/values:

```
<?php

$string = <<<EOS
version: 8.4.3 (api:1/proto:86-101)
srcversion: 6551AD2C98F533733BE558C

 1: cs:Connected ro:Primary/Secondary ds:UpToDate/UpToDate C r-----
    ns:1055689 nr:0 dw:7181 dr:1050351 al:6 bm:64 lo:0 pe:0 ua:0 ap:0 ep:1 wo:f oos:0
 2: cs:Connected ro:Secondary/Primary ds:UpToDate/UpToDate C r-----
    ns:0 nr:1048508 dw:1048508 dr:0 al:0 bm:64 lo:0 pe:0 ua:0 ap:0 ep:1 wo:f oos:0
 3: cs:SyncTarget ro:Secondary/Primary ds:Inconsistent/UpToDate C r----
    ns:0 nr:284320 dw:284320 dr:0 al:0 bm:17 lo:0 pe:0 ua:0 ap:0 ep:1 wo:b oos:764188
        [====>...............] sync\'ed: 27.4% (764188/1048508)K
        finish: 0:15:55 speed: 416 (320) K/sec
EOS;


$outerregex = '~
                ^version:\s
                (?P<version>[\d.]+)\s
                \(
                    api:(?P<api>\d+).+?
                    proto:(?P<proto>[-\d]+)
                \)\R
                srcversion:\s(?P<srcversion>.+)\R{2}
                (?P<devices>(?:\s\d(?:.+\R){2})+)
              ~xm';

$outerkeys = array("version", "api", "proto", "srcversion");

$output = array();
preg_match_all($outerregex, $string, $matches, PREG_SET_ORDER);

foreach ($matches as $match) {
    $arr = array();
    // save the outer key/value pairs
    foreach ($outerkeys as $key) $arr[$key] = $match[$key];

    $arr["devices"] = array();

    // split the device to have separate lines
    $lines = preg_split('~\R\s+\d:~', $match["devices"]);

    // loop over these lines
    foreach ($lines as $line) {
        $tmp = array();
        preg_match_all('~(?P<key>\w+):(?P<value>\S+)~', $line, $linematches, PREG_SET_ORDER);
        foreach ($linematches as $linematch)
            $tmp[$linematch["key"]] = $linematch["value"];
        $arr["devices"][] = $tmp;
    }

    $output[] = $arr;
}

print_r($output);
?>
```

Comment: Well, that's a whole bunch of fabulous voodoo at the moment, but it looks like a pretty good starting place! Thanks!

Comment: @adama: Look at the updated answer, logic and regex slightly changed in order to have all of your device data matched. Look at the ideone demo to see it's working.

Comment: With a bit of modification to this, I solved the problem. thanks! :)

Comment: @adama: Glad to help.